# json файл, внутри php функции

Tags: php

Почему ругается на синтаксис?

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
mb_internal_encoding('utf-8');

function getData(){
    $data = [{
      "firstName": "Иван",
      "lastName": "Иванов",
      "address": "г.Москва, ул. Алиева,2",
      "phoneNumber": "812 143-2534"
    }, {
      "firstName": "Вася",
      "lastName": "Пупкин",
      "address": "г.Воронеж, ул. Пушкина,11",
      "phoneNumber": "812 123-1234"
    }, {
      "firstName": "Сергей",
      "lastName": "Попов",
      "address": "г.Пермь, ул. Савина,30",
      "phoneNumber": "812 321-1444"
    }];

    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$data надо взять кавычки вот так

```
  $data = '[{....}]';
```

Comment: Потом не работает функция file_get_contents http://pastebin.com/r9Zmrda0

Comment: А чего б она работала, если  file_get_contents с файлами работает. $data - это уже JSON, достаточно json_decodе. , т.е. $decode = json_decode(getdata());

Comment: Вот примерчик накидал http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/30fd2919376a7488c45fa490ce279d707b3fd895

Answer (score 0):

Синтаксис PHP-объектов:

```
$obj = new stdObject();
$obj->name = "Nick";
$obj->surname = "Doe";
$obj->age = 20;
$obj->adresse = null;
```

Синтаксис PHP-массивов:

```
$array = array(
  1    => "a",
  "1"  => "b",
  1.5  => "c",
  true => "d",
);
```